# Display a list of file(s) depending on the value of a specific field in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, download

I've created a new 'jobs' content type on my Drupal 6 site, to enable administrator to post new jobs.

The content type has a hidden field called job_type, which can have 1 of 4 possible values: Instructor, Lecturer, Manager or Support.

How do I configure Drupal to dynamically display a list of files download based on the value of the job_type field?

The required files are already on the server.

For example:

```
if job_type = Manager, show: file1.pdf, file2.pdf
if job_type = Support, show: file1.pdf, file3.pdf, file5.pdf
if job_type = Lecturer, show: file1.pdf, file4.pdf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field).

something like

```
if ($node->field_job_type[0]['value']==Manager) { 
$node_field[0]['value'] = "path_to_file1.pdf";
$node_field[1]['value'] = "path_to_file2.pdf";
}
```

Then configure the display to print links to the files.

There are a lot of code snippets in the documentation at http://drupal.org/node/126522

Comment: @Chaulky @keva - Thanks for your help. I implemented a computed field using the example above, like so: `if($node->field_job_type[0]['value']==Instructor) { $node_field[0]['value'] = "sites/default/files/file1.pdf"; $node_field[1]['value'] = "sites/default/files/file5.pdf";}...`. How do I configure the **job_list** view to display hyperlinks to download these docs? I don't know why, but only 1 of the 2 required PDF files are listed as 'sites/default/files/file1.pdf', and I'm not sure how to have this path displayed as a link. Any ideas? Thank you.